# Fetch document on Firestore return sometimes client.user must not be null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

#### Environment

- Android Studio version: 4.0 canary 9
- Firebase Component: firebase-firestore-ktx, firebase-auth
- Component version Firestore: 21.4.3
- Component version Auth: 19.3.1

#### My problem

I'm using Auth Firebase sdk to signin/singup a user (email/password or gmail) and Firestore to retrieve user data.
Everything is working fine except for **5% of Android users** which have sometimes problems to retrieve Firestore data after a successful login. 
The error is : **client.user must not be null**

Everything is working fine on iOS, everything is ok for 95% of Android users, i can't reproduce it on my devices :'(

Sign in function with email/passwprd:

```
fun signin(
    email: String,
    password: String,
    callback: ((user: User?) -> Unit)
  ) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
          val user = auth.currentUser
          user?.let {
            fetchUser(it.uid, callback)
         }
      }
  ...
  }
```

And firestore function to retrieve user data, where the error happened :

```
fun fetchUser(authId: String, callback: ((user: User?) -> Unit)?) {
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    db.collection("users")
      .document(authId)
      .get()
      .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        try {
          if (document != null) {
            val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)
            user?.id = document.id
            callback?.let { it(user) }
          } else {
            callback?.let { it(null) }
          }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
          // print(e) => client.user must not be null
          manageError(ex)
          callback?.let { it(null) }
        }
      }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
        // print(e) => client.user must not be null
        manageError(e)
        callback?.let { it(null) }
      }
  }
```

Regards

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the data immediately after the user auth is generated? By the which line is giving the error?

Comment: Yes juste after, but i've added a second fetch directly after this error, and a second signin + fetch after this error. And it's still not good, user has to restart app or sign in later in the app. Maybe i should try to wait a bit yea.

The error is fire in the second function, in the addOnFailureListener or in the catch (dont know exactly)

Comment: First of all, post a screenshot of your database structure and then say what data you want to fetch. BUT the most important is how are you updating your data? I see you fetching the data but when are you uploading the data to the database? Please post that code too :-)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full error and stack trace which locations where the error happened.

Comment: I've added more informations, and  i will add more soon, but i don't have stack trace. I can't reproduce, i've got only some logs from firebase where i log the error message and from users telling me about the error...